# How to use jquery selector to select elements like this?

Tags: jquery-selectors, parent

suppose I have a html markup like this:

```
<div>
    <p>
       this is the parent
       <p>
          this the child
       </p>
    </p>
    <p>
       this is the parent
       <p>
          this the child
          <p>this is third child</p>
       </p>
    </p>
</div>
```

In the div I have five `<p>` tags,but I want only use jquery selector to select the two top parent p tag without class and id name

Is it possible?How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course, just do

```
$('div').children('p)
```

children only select the direct children of an element. Don't forget to set an id to your div...